# <activity> does not have a valid android:name when dexguarding

Tags: android, dexguard

I am trying to dexguard an application that I run as a system application.

However when I try to push it to the `system/app` directory, I get the following error from the PackageParser.

```
W/PackageParser( 1995): /system/app/My.apk (at Binary XML file line #290): <a
ctivity> does not have valid android:name
```

I have also added the following to the `dexguard-project.txt` but to no avail.

```
-keepresourcexmlattributenames
    manifest/installLocation,
    manifest/versionCode,
    manifest/package,
    manifest/versionName,
    manifest/application/*/intent-filter/*/name,
    manifest/application/*/activity/name
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Ok from what I see the `manifest/application/*/activity/name` successfully stopped the `android:name` attributes from being obfuscated in the manifest (I can see the plain text when I extract the manifest file after the obfuscation).

However strangely enough `android:name` in the activity tag at line `#290` cannot be found in the extracted manifest file. All the other activity names can be seen in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is because the activities that gave this error are in the manifest file but there were no respective java classes.

Removing the entries from manifest file solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the package name of the class started with a Capital letter

Comment: One phone was fine with capital letters, but another wasn't.